# Spark streaming sourceArchiveDir does not move file to archive directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using scala and spark with the version 3.4.1. While streaming using Spark, I give the `cleanSource` option as "archive" and the `sourceArchiveDir` option as "archived" as in the code below.

```
spark.readStream
  .option("cleanSource", "archive")
  .option("sourceArchiveDir", "archived")
  .option("enforceSchema", false)
  .option("header", includeHeader)
  .option("inferSchema", inferSchema)
  .options(otherOptions)
  .schema(csvSchema.orNull)
  .csv(FileUtils.getPath(sourceSettings.dataFolderPath, mappingSource.path).toString)
```

The code `FileUtils.getPath(sourceSettings.dataFolderPath, mappingSource.path)` returns a relative path like: test-data\streaming-folder\patients

When I start stream, spark does not move source csv to archive folder. After working on it a bit, I started debugging the spark source codes. I found the `override protected def cleanTask(entry: FileEntry): Unit` method in the `FileStreamSource.scala` file in the `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming` package.
On line 569, the `!fileSystem.rename(curPath, newPath)` code supposed to move source file to archive folder. However, when I debugged, I noticed that the curPath and newPath values were as follows:

**curPath**: `file:/C:/dev/be/data-integration-suite/test-data/streaming-folder/patients/patients-success.csv`

**newPath**: `file:/C:/dev/be/data-integration-suite/archived/C:/dev/be/data-integration-suite/test-data/streaming-folder/patients/patients-success.csv`

It seems that absolute path of csv file were appended when creating `newPath` because there are two `C:/dev/be/data-integration-suite` in the newPath. This is the reason spark archiving does not work. Instead, newPath should be: `file:/C:/dev/be/data-integration-suite/archived/test-data/streaming-folder/patients/patients-success.csv`. I know this is more related to spark library but I may not have much time to wait for them to fix this issue. Is there any workaround or spark config to overcome this problem?

I have tried to change paths of `readStream` but no change. I'm sure the paths in the `readStream` are relative.